serail.readline() not updating value with .after() method when measuring voltage with arduino/pc
I put the full code below because I'm not actually sure where the problem even is, but I can direct your attention to def read_analog() as that is the most likely location based on what is going wrong.
The objective is to read a 0-5 v DC voltage with the ardunio analog pin using the read_analog() to read the serial port every 2 seconds and print the value. The .after method was applied with the 2000 ms wait in order to 'free up' the code to execute anything else outside of the function as I am also sending data to maniuplate hardware. For some reason the read_analog() function is only reading the value from serial on the first iteration. After that it just repeats the same value every two seconds (may vary by 1) and does not respond to changes in the input voltage. I did confirm that the bits are be correctly received by the PC over serial so this is a python code issue. Oddly, if I use 'read_analog()' with the .after method instead of 'read_analog', it will loop non-stop but it does report the correct updated values.
Any thoughts?
Thanks!
import serial
import time
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import ttk
from pynput import keyboard
import tk_tools


step = 0
    
def quit_button():
    global tkTop
    ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))
    tkTop.destroy()

def on_button():
        varLabel.set("LED ON ")
        ser.write(bytes('H', 'UTF-8'))

def off_button():
        varLabel.set("LED OFF")
        ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))

def l_button():
        varLabel.set("Rotate Left")
        ser.write(bytes('L', 'UTF-8'))
        global step
        step = step - 1
        progressbar.step(step)
        p.set_value(step)
        print("Step",step)
        #varLabel.set("LED OFF")
        ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))

def r_button():
        varLabel.set("Rotate Right")
        ser.write(bytes('R', 'UTF-8'))
        global step
        step =  step + 1
        progressbar.step(step)
        p.set_value(step)
        print("Step",step)
        #varLabel.set("LED OFF")
        ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.right:
       r_button()
    if key == keyboard.Key.left:
       l_button()

def read_analog():
         value = ser.readline().decode()
         value = value.rstrip('\r\n')  # Remove carriage return
         #valueint = int(float((value)))
         print('Voltage', value, ' volts')
         tkTop.after( 2000, read_analog) # period depends on how frequent the arduino writes data to its serial port

         
        
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press)
listener.start()



#change the COM port below
ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600, timeout=0.1)
print("Reset Arduino")
time.sleep(2)
ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))


tkTop = tkinter.Tk()
tkTop.geometry('400x400') #500 x 500 window
tkTop.title("LED control") #name in title bar
# Create a parent frame
parent_frame = tkinter.Frame(tkTop)
parent_frame.pack()

tkTop.after( 2000, read_analog()) # period depends on how frequent the arduino writes data to its serial port

#define button images
upimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('voltup.png').resize((60,60)))
downimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('voltdown.png').resize((60,60)))

#label to display the status
varLabel = tkinter.IntVar()
tkLabel = tkinter.Label(textvariable=varLabel, )
varLabel.set("LED STATUS")
tkLabel.pack()

#label for HV controls
HVlabel = tkinter.Label(text= "HV Control")
HVlabel.place(x=300, y=40),

#button1 - ON
button1 = tkinter.IntVar()
button1state = tkinter.Button(tkTop,
    text="ON",
    command=on_button,
    height = 4,
    width = 8,
    bg = 'green'

)
button1state.pack(side='top', ipadx=10, padx=10, pady=15)

#button2 - OFF
button2 = tkinter.IntVar()
button2state = tkinter.Button(tkTop,
    text="OFF",
        command=off_button,
    height = 4,
    width = 8,
)
button2state.pack(side='top', ipadx=10, padx=10, pady=15)

#button3 - Rotate Right
button3 = tkinter.IntVar()
button3state = tkinter.Button(tkTop,
    text="Rotate Right",
        command=r_button,
    height = 60,
    width = 60,
    image = upimage
)
button3state.place(x=300, y=60)



#button4 - Rotate Left
button4 = tkinter.IntVar()
button4state = tkinter.Button(tkTop,
    text="Rotate Left",
        command=l_button,
    height = 60,
    width = 60,
    image = downimage
)
button4state.place(x=300, y=180)

#Quit button
tkButtonQuit = tkinter.Button(
    tkTop,
    text="Quit",
    command=quit_button,
    height = 4,
    width = 8,
)

p = tk_tools.RotaryScale(tkTop, max_value = 60, unit = "step")
p.place(x=300, y =300)
#print("step",step)
tkTop.title("Progress Bar in Tk")
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(maximum=1500)
progressbar.place(x=400, y=60, width=160)


    

tkButtonQuit.pack(side='top', ipadx=10, padx=10, pady=15)
tkinter.mainloop()


Firstly, tkTop.after( 2000, read_analog()) should probably be tkTop.after(2000, read_analog). Secondly, does ser.readline() wait for a line to be written? If so, then the GUI can't update while your program is waiting for a line. Thirdly, can you please add more information about what is happening vs what you expect to happen?

Since you have set timeout=0.1 when creating instance of serial.Serial(), then it is not guaranteed that readline() returns a line with trailing newline. Suggest to call readline() in blocking mode in a child thread instead of using after loop.

Thanks for the reply. I'm uncertain if ser.readline() waits for a line to be written. I didn't see anything about it in the official documentation.

There is explanation in offical document.

@acw1668 So appreciate the help! That may be too complex for me? I have no idea what a child thread is. I did read the documentation, but I must have been too dumb to see anything helpful?

@TheLizzard To answer your question: What I want to have happen is for the code to read the serial port value, print it to terminal, delay for 2 seconds while it sees if anything else is executed, and then read the serial data again...and continue like that.
What is happening instead is that it reads the value one first run and then reports the same initial value over and over again every 2 seconds. It isn't updating with new serial data which I confirmed is making it to the PC.

I was able to get this to work well but using ser.flushinput() before each read. This forces the program to re-evaluate the value vs. using the same number.
This is probably a horrible solution. I still don't know why the serial wasn't re-reading with every pass. I figured maybe because the documentation stated .readline only reads one line. I tried .readlines and that just froze the program and it wouldn't start up.

Suggest to create instance of Serial without setting timeout option.  Then use ser.in_waiting to check whether there is data ready to be read.
...

ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600)  # don't set timeout option

...

def read_analog():
    if ser.in_waiting > 5:  # size of (value + newline), change it to suit your case
        value = ser.readline().decode().rstrip()
        print(f'Voltage: {value} volts')
    tkTop.after(1000, read_analog) # period depends on how frequent the arduino writes data to its serial port

read_analog()  # start the after loop

...


Or using threading.Thread to execute read_analog() in a child thread:
...
import time
import threading
...
ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600)
...
def read_analog():
    while True:
        value = ser.readline().decode().rstrip()
        print(f'Voltage: {value} volts')
        time.sleep(1)

threading.Thread(target=read_analog, daemon=True).start()
...


Thank you for putting the time into that for me. I appreciate the help! I'm going take a look at it.
